# What does 'half life' of a protein mean?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins

Why do we use the term 'half life' for proteins?

[Here](https://www.nature.com/articles/npp2008190) is a link to some information regarding this question, but I am unable to infer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Half-life time" [is a general term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life). This is a time after which the amount of substance X decreases by 50%.

If you take a bulk of something (say, 100 protein molecules), if this protein has half-life time of 1 hr, then 1 hr later you'll have 50 molecules left.

In cellular biology it usually means that 50% of protein got recycled/degraded in given half-life time

Comment: why is not the term "life time" used?

Comment: @souravthampan comparing to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence-lifetime_imaging_microscopy I think main difference is that "lifetime" is a characteristic of process, which can be measured by "half life" time.